# Some server garbled when use UrlConnection?

Tags: java

I use below code to post some data,but i find In some server the response string is garbled(not all servers).

```
  URL url = new URL("http://url");
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
      .openConnection();
  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setDoInput(true);
  connection.setRequestMethod(method);
  connection.setUseCaches(false);
  connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
  connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", String_UTF_8);
  connection.setRequestProperty("contentType", String_UTF_8);
  connection.connect();
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(newOutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(),String_UTF_8));
  out.println(json);
  out.close();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), String_UTF_8));
  String lines;
  while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      lines = new String(lines.getBytes());
      sb.append(lines);
  }
  reader.close();
  connection.disconnect();
```

I tried a lot of ways,but all have no effect.

Comment: What is `String_UTF_8` ? Removes `lines = new String(lines.getBytes());` from your code it is useless as you already have a `String`.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto,remove the line,and The problem is solved.You should answer the question instead of comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use [`String#getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) it will decode your `String` using the **platform's default charset** which means that it is **platform dependent**. Moreover as you have already decoded your stream content as `String` using `UTF-8` as charset, it is even **useless**.

**Try this instead:**

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), String_UTF_8))
) {
    String lines;
    while ((lines = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(lines);
    }
}
```